# Visual Studio 2019 Preview 5.0 collection view cells must have reuse identifier

Tags: c#, uicollectionview, visual-studio-2019

When I drag a collectionView onto my storyboard I get a warning that states `collection view cells must have reuse identifier`.  I watched the YouTube video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weJQ7UX61JU but this project is Xamarin Studio, not Visual Studio and Visual Studio does not have a `Collection Reusable View` box in the widget area.  I created all my code EXACTLY as the video describes and I get absolutely nothing displayed.  I assume it's because I have to connect the `cell` class to the `CollectionView` somehow, but I cannot find a place in the view on the story board like Xamarin Studio where I do that.  Everything in the `cvSource` code is hit EXCEPT `GetCell` and I cannot find anything on the web that describes this problem never mind solve it.  What am I missing?

My code:

Cell Code:

```
class ParticipantCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    UIImageView imageView;
    public UIImage Image;

    public static NSString participantCellId = new NSString("ParticipantCell");
    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public ParticipantCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        BackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0) };

        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };

        ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        ContentView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.8f, 0.8f);



        imageView = new UIImageView();
        // imageView.ContentMode = ;
        imageView.Image = Image;
        imageView.Center = ContentView.Center;
        imageView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.7f, 0.7f);

        ContentView.AddSubview(new UIView() { imageView });
    }
}
```

CollectionView Source Code

```
class CVSource : UICollectionViewSource
{
    DataSet Participants = new DataSet();

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return Participants.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    }

    public CVSource(DataSet pParticipants)
    {
        Participants = pParticipants;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var participantCell = (ParticipantCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(ParticipantCell.participantCellId, indexPath);
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])Participants.Tables[0].Rows[indexPath.Row]["Photo"];
        UIImage Mybitmap = GetImagefromByteArray(imageBytes);
        participantCell.Image = MaxResizeImage(Mybitmap, 200f, 200f);
        return participantCell;
    }

    public static UIImage GetImagefromByteArray(byte[] imageBuffer)
    {
        NSData imageData = NSData.FromArray(imageBuffer);
        return UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
    }
    public static UIImage MaxResizeImage(UIImage sourceImage, float maxWidth, float maxHeight)
    {
        var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size;
        var maxResizeFactor = Math.Min(maxWidth / sourceSize.Width, maxHeight / sourceSize.Height);
        if (maxResizeFactor > 1) return sourceImage;
        var width = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Width;
        var height = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Height;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize((nfloat)width, (nfloat)height));
        sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, (nfloat)width, (nfloat)height));
        var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return resultImage;
    }
}
```

story board code, the `CollectionView` name is `cvParticipants`

```
public partial class Participants : UIViewController
{
    public User MyUser;
    public string company = "";
    public string department = "";
    public string section = "";
    public Participants(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface myService = new DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface();
        DataSet dbParticipants = myService.GetParticipantsWithPhoto(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password, company, department, section, "CURRENT");

        viewParticipants.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        var width = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Width;

        cvParticipants.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ParticipantCell), ParticipantCell.participantCellId);

        cvParticipants.Source = new CVSource(dbParticipants);


        lblTitle.Text = section + " Participants";

        viewParticipants.AddConstraints(

            banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

            lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
            lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner),
            cvParticipants.Below(lblTitle, 0),
            cvParticipants.WithSameWidth(lblTitle)
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to set the `CollectionView`'s height.  I changed the constraints to:

```
    viewParticipants.AddConstraints(

        banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
        banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
        banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
        lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
        lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner),
        cvParticipants.WithSameWidth(banner),
        cvParticipants.WithSameHeight(View),
        cvParticipants.Below(lblTitle, 0)
    );
```

I'll have to come up with a way to set the `CollectionView`'s height so that it will be at the bottom of the `View`, but at least I got the collection to display.